# Task<IEnumerable<T>> thread safety issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am creating all the variables within a task and I don't see any shared state. One of the `MyData` value (eg: `myData.Chocolate`) was null in one of the instances where I made a call. I didn't have logs when I made the call and I am unable to replicate it. I wasn't sure if the external call returned a null or if there was any threading issue which caused the field to be null during the specific instance.

Do you see any thread safety issues in the program below?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyData>> MyMethodAsync(IEnumerable<string> data)
{
    var tasks = data.Select(async d =>
    {
        MyData myData = new MyData();

        //API call
        CandyData candyData = // await async API call to Graph Client

        myData.Chocolate = candyData.Chocolate;
        myData.Toffee = candyData.Toffee;
        // more similar setters

        return myData;
    });
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return results;
}
```

Comment: there seems to be missing something `CandyData candyData = `

Comment: @nbk it is an API call to Graph CLient

Comment: that is a vital information, it can be the cause of the thread problem.

Comment: How do you know that the source of the `null` `myData.Chocolate` is not a `null` `candyData.Chocolate`? If the second is `null`, the first will be `null` too, because you assign the one to the other.

Comment: What happens if you move the `MyData myData = new MyData();` until after the async call?

Comment: As a side note, I dislike the `Task<IEnumerable<MyData>>` return type for being too abstract. `Task<MyData[]>` would be more specific, and would allow the caller of the method more freedom with interacting with the returned data.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, I believe that could be have been null but I wasn't able to replicate that behavior for the external service. So I was just trying to see if thread safety could be an issue.

Comment: When multiple threads are sharing a state or data thread safety comes into play. In your example, every thread manipulates its own data. So it is safe.

Comment: @Eldar - that's correct, however the *`await async API call to Graph Client`* call might possibly resume on a different thread, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/xWDAco.  So it's possible that some state set up before the `async` call will be stale afterwards.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine.

I tested it with the following:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var results = await MyMethodAsync(new [] { "A", "B", "C", });
    foreach (var result in results)
        Console.WriteLine(result.Chocolate);
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<MyData>> MyMethodAsync(IEnumerable<string> data)
{
    var tasks = data.Select(async d =>
    {
        MyData myData = new MyData();

        CandyData candyData = await GetCandyDataAsync(d);

        myData.Chocolate = candyData.Chocolate;
        myData.Toffee = candyData.Toffee;

        return myData;
    });
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return results;
}

public Task<CandyData> GetCandyDataAsync(string data) =>
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0));
        return new CandyData()
        {
            Chocolate = data,
            Toffee = data
        };
    });
```

That produced `A`, `B`, `C` to the console after 10 seconds as expected.

This means that any issue could be in your implementation of `GetCandyDataAsync`.

My next thought was to try to clean up the code to make it more maintainable and testable.

So, I wrote this extension method based on your `MyMethodAsync`:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<R>> SelectMany<T, U, R>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, Task<U>> taskSelector,
        Func<T, U, R> resultSelector) =>
    await Task.WhenAll(
        source
            .Select(async t =>
            {
                U u = await taskSelector(t);
                R r = resultSelector(t, u);
                return r;
            }));
```

Yes, that effectively your code wrapped in a `SelectMany` that can now be used to write a simple LINQ query implementation of your `MyMethodAsync` method.

Here it is:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyData>> MyMethodAsync(IEnumerable<string> data) =>
    await
        from d in data
        from candyData in GetCandyDataAsync(d)
        select new MyData()
        {
            Chocolate = candyData.Chocolate,
            Toffee = candyData.Toffee,
        };
```

Again, that produces the same result as above, but it's encapsulated the hard work in a handy extension method.

I fully tested before posting.